# <OpenLayers3> Make choropleth map with GeoJson

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I try to make a **choropleth** map with **OpenLayers3** and a **GeoJson** generate in a **javascript**.

I want to use the properties of my **GeoJson** for make this map.

For Example, if I've a city with properties `["name"='1']` and a city with properties `["name"='2']` I want to have blue color for the '1' and red color for the '2'.

I found on the internet, how to make this map with OpenLayers2 ([Example for make a **choropleth** map with `OL2][1])` but I don't find the equivalence in **OL3**. The code with **OL2** look like :

```
var subteStyleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
'strokeWidth': 4
});

var lookup = {
  "1": {strokeColor: "#46C7FA"},
  "2": {strokeColor: "#E81D1A"}
}

subteStyleMap.addUniqueValueRules("default", "number", lookup);

var geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GeoJSON", {
   projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
   strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
   protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
      url: "generation_geojson2.php",
      format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
   }),
   styleMap: subteStyleMap
});
```

I started the adaptation but I don't find the equivalence for 'addUniqueValueRules'

```
var lookup = {
  "1": {strokeColor: "#46C7FA"},
  "2": {strokeColor: "#E81D1A"}
}

subteStyleMap.addUniqueValueRules("default", "number", lookup);

var vector_arret_tad    = new ol.layer.Vector
                            ({
                            source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({ url: 'generation_geojson2.php',defaultProjection :'EPSG:4326', projection: 'EPSG:3857'}), 
                            name: 'City',
                            style: subteStyleMap
                            });
```

What is the OL3 equivalence of this code, or another solution for this problem?

Comment: does this involve Google Maps at all?

Comment: I don't think it does. The google-maps and gwt-openlayers tags should probably be removed.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the tags google-maps and gwt-openlayers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a style function. A style function is a function that takes a feature as an argument and returns an array of style object.

In your case, it will look like this:

```js
var lookup = {
  "1": [new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "#46C7FA"
    })
  })],
  "2": [new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "#E81D1A"
    })
  })]
};

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  // …
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return lookup[feature.get('number')];
  }
});
```

See http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-layer.html for an example that uses a style function to add labels to polygons.